# compare two tables for matching and update or move and delete rows

Tags: c#, sql, duplicates, matching

I have two tables which I need to compare if there are values that are matching in both. 
Structure of tables

```
Persons
ID | fname | lname | address | socialNumber | taxNumber | Match

Personals
ID | fname | lname | address | socialNumber | taxNumber
```

I have two parameters that are being check for matching, socialNumber AND/OR taxNumber.

1. Person need to be compared with Personals
2. If match is found update ID (in Persons) with ID of Personals (the one that is matching) and set "Match" to True (default is false)
3. If match is not found delete row from Persons and insert it as new row in Personals
4. List item

Also, If it is possible to have everything dynamic as possible if I would like to add new parameters to look for matching (example: address). 
This is my SQL code that I'm using it right now but I don't know how to expand it for my needs.

```
 UPDATE Persons SET Match = 1, ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Personals) WHERE taxNumber IN ( SELECT taxNumber FROM Personals GROUP BY taxNumber HAVING ( COUNT(taxNumber) > 1 ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can easily do this in a single query, not without using a cursor, but you could just break the action into two parts like these:

```
--update action
update  a 
set a.id = b.id, a.match =1
from _persons a inner join _personals b 
on a.social = b.social or a.taxnumber = b.taxnumber

--delete / insert action
declare @RowCount as integer
select  @RowCount = count(a.id) from _persons a  
where ID not in (
        select a.id
        from _persons a inner join _personals b 
        on a.social = b.social or a.taxnumber = b.taxnumber
    )

if @RowCount>0 
begin
insert into _Personals (ID, fname, lname, address, social, taxnumber)
select ID, fname, lname, address, social, taxnumber from _persons a
where ID not in (
                select a.id
                from _persons a inner join _personals b 
                on a.social = b.social or a.taxnumber = b.taxnumber
            )
delete _persons
where ID not in 
    (
            select a.id
            from _persons a inner join _personals b 
            on a.social = b.social or a.taxnumber = b.taxnumber
    )
end
```